# The original paper by Kutta

Tags: mathematics

The Runge-Kutta method is a milestone of computational mathematics. I can find the papepr by Runge, but not the one by Kutta.

By wikipedia, the title is **Beitrag zur näherungweisen Integration totaler Differentialgleichungen** (1901)

Can anyone find it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a facsimile of the journal: https://archive.org/stream/zeitschriftfrma12runggoog#page/n449/mode/2up.  See pp. 435f.